# how can divide time to two part?

Tags: angular, typescript

For example we get 12:34 from user and want to split it in two diffrent part and save it in an array like this [12, 34]
how could do this in angular?

I tried to split them but those solution was wrong!
I'm working with `<ngx-timepicker-field>` in angular and this is my html data

```
<ngx-timepicker-field 
     timepickerClass="custom-timepicker-css"
     [defaultTime]="'00:00'"
     [formControlName]="'start_time'"
     [format]="24"
     [clockTheme]="theme"
></ngx-timepicker-field>
```

Comment: is it ok if its split on save alone, the form will contain the normal value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` function to split string value and store it in another value using the below code.

```
const startTimeValue: string = this.myForm.get('start_time').value;
const timeArray: string[] = startTimeValue.split(':');
```

From above code you will get [12, 34] in `timeArray`.

*Note*: * Here *this.myForm* is your `ForGroup`'s name.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a getter method to access the split value!

```
get splitDate() {
    const value = this.formControlItem && this.formControlItem.value;
    if (value.includes('AM') || value.includes('PM')) {
      const split = value && value.split(':');
      const amPm =
        (split && split[1] && split[1].substr(-2, split[1].length)) || 'AM';
      return value
        ? [split[0], split[1].substr(0, split[1].length - 2), amPm]
        : [];
    } else {
      return (value && value.split(':')) || [];
    }
  }

  get splitDateWithPadding() {
    const value = this.formControlItem && this.formControlItem.value;
    if (value.includes('AM') || value.includes('PM')) {
      const split = value && value.split(':');
      const amPm =
        (split && split[1] && split[1].substr(-2, split[1].length)) || 'AM';
      const firstPadded = split[0] && split[0].padStart(2, '0');
      const split1 = split[1].substr(0, split[1].length - 2);
      const secondPadded = split1 && split1.padStart(2, '0');
      return value ? [firstPadded, secondPadded, amPm] : [];
    } else {
      return (value && value.split(':')) || [];
    }
  }
```

html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>MY FIELD</mat-label>
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    [ngxMatTimepicker]="timepicker"
    [format]="12"
    [required]="required"
    readonly
    [formControl]="formControlItem"
  />

  <mat-icon
    matPrefix
    *ngIf="formControlItem.value && !formControlItem.disabled && !required"
    (click)="onClear($event)"
  >
    close
  </mat-icon>

  <mat-icon
    matSuffix
    *ngIf="!formControlItem.disabled"
    (click)="openFromIcon(timepicker)"
    >schedule</mat-icon
  >
</mat-form-field>

<ngx-mat-timepicker
  #timepicker
  [enableKeyboardInput]="true"
  [max]="maxTime"
  [min]="minTime"
></ngx-mat-timepicker>
<br />
{{ formControlItem.value | json }}
<br />
<br />
{{ splitDate | json }}

<br />
<br />
{{ splitDateWithPadding | json }}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-timepicker-qayv8e)